# What is the recommended approach to test a model from another database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, tdd

I am developping a new application using TDD for the first time.
One of the requirement is to reuse a table that already exists for another project.
There is two database, one for my new app, one for the already existing project.

I have a model created in my new applications that references that other model.

`GainCode (new app) -> belongsTo Company (existing app)`

My first idea was to create a factory for both of these model for my test, but then I realised that because I set the `protected $connection` property on my `Company` model, it actually inserts data in the real table during the tests.
I tried to add the following code in the model to change the connectiong if it is under test environment:

```php
 public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        if (App::environment('testing')) {
            $this->connection = 'sqlite';
        }
    }
```

However, I noticed this does not work because I have no migration file for a `Company`.

I then decided to remove the factory and use `Company::first()` in my test instead and factory.

*Before*

```php
'company_id' => function() {
    return Company::factory()->create()->ID;
}
```

*After*

```php
class GainCodeFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'code' => $this->faker->unique()->randomNumber(5),
            'description_fr' => $this->faker->sentence(5),
            'description_en' => $this->faker->sentence(5),
            'inactive' => $this->faker->boolean(),
            'company_id' => function() {
                return Company::first()->ID;
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

*Unit test sample*

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\Company;
use App\Models\GainCode;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class GainCodeTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function it_belongs_to_a_company()
    {
        $company = Company::first(); // BEFORE: Company::factory()->create();
        $gainCode = GainCode::factory()->create(['company_id' => $company->ID]);
        $this->assertEquals($company->ID, $gainCode->company->ID);
    }
}
```

What is the recommended way to do TDD with such requirement?
Should I revert back to using factory and maintain a migration file for that table?

Comment: You just need to run `config(['database.connections.CONNECTION_NAME.host' => 'YOUR_TEST_HOST'])`, only if you have a local database/table. I had a similar "issue" in my company and what I ended up doing was having a trait that would use the `setUp` and run local migrations or manual creations on a `host` I have on docker just for testing DBs. So I have a local table exactly the same as in prod (without the data), and then I update with the config I shared, what `host` to use (docker host) so I can use that local DB testing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have also created the table in your local database, and when the app_env is "testing", you set the connection property of the model to the local database. All the other times, you are referencing the real table in the "remote" database with the real data?

Comment: Yes, but not exactly as you mentioned. Remember that, when you run `phpunit`, you use `phpunit.xml`, so you can set any `env` in there, so I already set the `host` of that connection to be the testing database (a local database just for testing purposes).